# using PostgreSQL in Rails , search with ILIKE when Value have brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

using PostgreSQL in Rails, i have a model Logs with attribute **value**:

I have this Log:

```
Id:46
Value: "Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython>=7.23.1->ipykernel->notebook>=4.3.1->jupyterlab) (0.18.1)"
```

it has brackets in the value.

when i'm trying to Use ILIKE search it find me nothing if i have a brackets in the search:

so i'm searching like that:

```
query = "%Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from%"
Logs.where("value ILIKE ?",query.downcase)
```

but i get nil

when i search without a bracket:

```
query = "%Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages%"
Logs.where("value ILIKE ?",query.downcase)
```

its working and returns me a value.

i tried doing something like:

```
value.gsub("(","//("
ILIKE ? ESCAPE '//'

but its still didn't work
```

i would glad for some help

Comment: I tried with the bracket and it works for me with rails 6.1 (PG DB). But if it is not working for you, you can try replacing the symbols with `%` and hopefully, that should do the trick.

Comment: i'm using rails 5. with %? it didn't work replacing it.

Comment: What is the actual query produced by each? You should be able to find this in the logs.